# How can I create Accordion using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an accordion in which by default one step is open by default and the rest of the steps can be opened by clicking on an edit button. Structure defined below.

```
Step 1

Hello world. Lorem ipsum.
--------------------------------------------
Step 2                                  Edit
--------------------------------------------
Step 3                                  Edit
--------------------------------------------
Step 4                                  Edit
```

Now as you see step 1's content is visible by default. So if I click on Step 2's "edit" button, Step 1 should be collapsed and Step 2's content should be visible.

This is what I have come up so far.

HTML:

```
<h6 class="ml-3 mt-3 step-1"><a id="step-one" href="#">Step 1</a></h6>
<br style="clear:both;">
<div id="promo-code" class="mt-5 ml-3">
<p>Abc content</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
</div>

<hr class="ml-3">

<div class="mt-5 ml-3" id="promo-box">
<h6>Step 2</h6>
<p>Abc content</p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#promo-code").click(function(){
document.getElementById("promo-code").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("promo-box").style.display = "block";
});

$("#step-one").click(function(){
document.getElementById("promo-code").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("promo-box").style.display = "none";
});
```

CSS:

```
#promo-code {
font-size: 15px;
color: #02b875;
}

#promo-box {
display: none;
}

.step-1 {
margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered jQueryUI?  It comes with an accordion widget out of the box

Comment: Yes, but wanted to make a custom accordion.

Comment: How? you [Google](https://www.jqueryscript.net/accordion/) and find [ones](https://freefrontend.com/jquery-accordions/) on Github and learn how it was done. that's how..

Comment: Noted sir. I shall be doing this right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap, here is the bootstrap example. Run this snippet, functionality is almost same like what you wanted to achieve, modify as required.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0"> Step 1
        <button class="btn btn-link float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Edit</button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0"> Step 2
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Edit</button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">Step 3
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Edit
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I don't want Edit link on the opened tab? Because it's already opened and it won't make sense to have edit on it.

Comment: Use aria-expanded="true" attribute and hide it in js/CSS

Comment: Any example of this? Because I noticed you're already using aira-expanded="true" and it's the same.

Comment: Lucky day I guess, Add this CSS `button[aria-expanded="true"]{
  display: none;
}`